# Get non null value from an object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

Let's say I have a class `Foo` which has X and X has Y. 
I want to get Y from X only if `foo.getX()` is not `null` otherwise `null` as shown below :

```
Y y = getNonNullValue(foo.getX(), X::getY);
```

So I don't have to do :

```
if (foo.getX() != null) {
    Y y = foo.getX().getY();
}
```

I have the following code

```
public <T, R> R getNonNullValue(final T t, final Supplier<R> supplier) {
    return ; // What to write here?
}
```

Does `commons-lang` or any other library has similar functionality?

Comment: What do you want `getNonNullValue` to return when `t` is `null`?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question, but i supose you need this :

```
public <T, R> R getNonNullValue(final T t, final Function<T, R> mapper) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(t)
                    .map(mapper)
                    .orElse(null);
}
```

or as suggested by jesper:

```
public <T, R> R getNonNullValue(final T t, final Supplier<R> supplier) {
        return t != null ? supplier.get() : null;
}
```

Comment: Or just `return t != null ? supplier.get() : null;`. But that assumes that OP wants to get `null` back when `t` is `null`.

Comment: sur, you can do it that way alose :

public <T, R> R getNonNullValue(final T t, final Supplier<R> supplier) {
  return t != null ? supplier.get() : null;
 }

Comment: The first option works fine. With the second option I get an error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method `getNonNullValue`.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not clear what you want your method `getNonNullValue` to return when `foo.getX()` returns `null`. Assuming you'll want it to return `null`, then you can simply do this:

```
public <T, R> R getNonNullValue(final T t, final Supplier<R> supplier) {
    return t != null ? supplier.get() : null;
}
```

However, you can only call it like you are trying to if `getY` is a `static` method in class `X`:

```
// For this to work, X.getY() must be static
Y y = getNonNullValue(foo.getX(), X::getY);
```

That's probably not what you want; I think that you want to call the non-`static` `getY` method on the object that `foo.getX()` returns. If that's the case, then you should call `getNonNullValue` like this:

```
Y y = getNonNullValue(foo.getX(), foo.getX()::getY);
```

I doubt whether this makes your code more clear and concise than just directly writing the following:

```
Y y = foo.getX() != null ? foo.getX().getY() : null;
```

Java unfortunately does not have a null-safe dereferencing operator like a number of other programming languages have, which would make this more concise and clear.

Comment: You're right it is the second option I wanted. The code you posted throws `NullPointerException` when `foo.getX()` is null as expected, So it does not serve my purpose.